# Multiple affiliation in JSS article template

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

Is it possible to add two affiliations and add two or more lines for a long affiliation in JSS article template?

```
---
documentclass: jss
author:
  - name: Name1 Surname1
    affiliation: affiliation1,affiliation2
    address: >
      address1
      address2
    email: \email{email@email.com}
  - name: Name2 Surname2
    affiliation: Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long affiliation
title:
  formatted: "Title"
  plain:     "Title"
  short:     "Short Title"
abstract: >
  This paper introduces ...
keywords:
  # at least one keyword must be supplied
  formatted: [keyword1 ,keyword2]
  plain:     [keyword1 ,keyword2]
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
output: 
  rticles::jss_article
bibliography: refs.bib
---
```

[image]